# Melt data.table according to nested list

Tags: r, list, data.table

I had a data.table like this:

```
library(data.table)    
dt <- data.table(a = c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 3)), b = c(1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6))
```

I needed to perform an operation (forecast) on the values for each `a`, so I decided to put them in a list, like this:

```
dt <- dt[, x := .(list(b)), by = a][, .SD[1,], by = a, .SDcols = "x"]
```

Now I wanted to "melt" (that's the thing that comes to mind) `dt` back into its original form.

I could do it for very few levels of `a` like this:

```
dt2 <- rbind(expand.grid(dt[1, a], dt[1, x[[1]]]), expand.grid(dt[2, a], dt[2, x[[1]]]))
```

but of course, the solution is impractical for more levels of `a`.

I've tried

```
dt2 <- dt[, expand.grid(a, x[[1]]), by = a]
```

which results in

```
dt2
##    a Var1 Var2
## 1: A    A    1
## 2: A    A    3
## 3: A    A    5
## 4: B    A    2
## 5: B    A    4
## 6: B    A    6
```

it's interesting to notice that `Var1` doesn't actually follow the "A - B" pattern expected (but at least `a` remains).

Is there a better approach to achieve this?

#### EDITS

Expected output will be the result of

```
dt2[, .(a, Var2)]
```

- Corrected "melt" for "dcast".

Comment: Does `dt[, unlist(x), a]` give you what you need?

Comment: Can you show the expected otuput

Comment: I think your title is misleading as `dcast` is for reshaping from long to wide format, here it is to convert the nested list to `long` format (if i understand the problem)

Comment: A tidyr option is `library(tidyr);unnest(dt, b=x)`

Comment: @Psidom yes it does! I'll be glad to accept it as an answer, once you provide it as such.

Comment: Just made an answer below. Hope it clarifies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for a method to `nest`(convert a column from a atomic vector type to list type) and `unnest`(the opposite direction) in a data.table way. This is different from reshaping data which either `spread` a column values to row header(`dcast`) or `gather` the row headers to a column values(`melt`):

In data.table syntax, you can use `list` and `unlist` on the target column to summarize or broadcast it along with group variables:

Say if we are starting from:

```
dt
#    a b
# 1: A 1
# 2: A 3
# 3: A 5
# 4: B 2
# 5: B 4
# 6: B 6
```

To repeat what you have achieved in your first step, i.e. `nest` column `b`, you can do:

```
dt_nest <- dt[, .(b = list(b)), a]
dt_nest
#    a     b
# 1: A 1,3,5
# 2: B 2,4,6
```

To go the opposite direction, use `unlist` with the group variable:

```
dt_nest[, .(b = unlist(b)), a]
#    a b
# 1: A 1
# 2: A 3
# 3: A 5
# 4: B 2
# 5: B 4
# 6: B 6
```